# Terraform/AWS - Reusable archive_file block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, policy

I'm brand new to Terraform and AWS, and after looking for a long time online I still can't make sense of how this is doable. I would really appreciate the help.

```
data "archive_file" "archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${reference to any lambda which requires it}"
  output_path = "${specified output_path somehow dictated by the lambda?}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello_world" {
  function_name = "HelloWorld"

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket.id
  s3_key    = aws_s3_object.lambda_hello_world.key

  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
  handler = "hello.handler"

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_hello_world.output_base64sha256
(this will somehow let archive_file know what the source_file and output_path are)

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn
}
```

Would it be possible for me to achieve something like this? It would mean I'd only have to write the block for `archive_file` one time but have it change its variables per lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through `for_each`. For that,your files would have to be in a map, e.g.:

```
variable "files" {
   default = {
     "function1" = {
        source_file = "..."
        output_path = "..."
      },
     "function2" = {
        source_file = "..."
        output_path = "..."
      }              
   }
}

data "archive_file" "archive" {
 
  for_each  = var.files  

  type        = "zip"
  source_file = each.value.source_file
  output_path = each.value.output_path 
}
```

then you have only **one function** code:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "hello_world" {

  for_each  = var.files  

  function_name = "HelloWorld" # name also must be unique

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket.id
  s3_key    = aws_s3_object.lambda_hello_world.key

  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
  handler = "hello.handler"

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_hello_world[each.key].output_base64sha256

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn
}
```